# GA add on - Automated run(Scheduled run) doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

[image]
[image]

I have a few automated reports on google sheets using the GA add on. Each of these reports have a number of sheets which need to be updated on an automated scheduled run (GA add on ->Scheduled run) .These were running just fine for until a couple of weeks back .

However, now,my automated reports wouldn't update the google sheets anymore unless I run it manually .

The manual updates seem to OK and the GA content loads just fine.

What could have gone wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: do you use `getActiveSheet` in your code? if yes, then change it to `getSheetByName(sheetName)` and indicate the `sheetName` of the specific sheet. This is a question based on an assumption because only assumptions can be made if you don't show us any code.

Comment: Thanks for responding Marios . I am only using the GA add on and hence no code was used . I used the scheduled run as attached in the images and the report configuration .I wanted to understand what areas could've gone wrong with the configuration .

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can happen, there can be several reasons (trigger conflict, authentication failure, etc ...) but they are not demonstrable since the errors are visible only by the owner of the add-on.

Try to uncheck schedule and save, put it back and save. If that doesn't work, copy your reports to a new Spreadsheet and activate the schedule there.

Comment: Thanks ,yes.making a new sheet definitely did the trick!